# Node.js cluster error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-cluster

Hello i am very new to node.js and javascript, i am trying to create a culster.js with the nodejs cluster module, at the end of my if statement i am calling server.js to start the app.

cluster.js

```
const cluster = require('cluster');
const cpuCount = require('os').cpus().length;
const startServer = require('./server');

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  for (let i = 0; i < cpuCount; i += 1) {
    cluster.fork();
  }
  cluster.on('exit', () => {
    cluster.fork();
  });
} else {
  return startServer;
}
```

server.js

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const express = require('express');
const auth = require('http-auth');
const {
  createBundleRenderer,
} = require('vue-server-renderer');

const bundle = fs.readFileSync('dist/server.js', 'utf-8');
const renderer = createBundleRenderer(bundle);

function parseIndexHtml() {
  const [
    entire,
    htmlOpen,
    htmlOpenTailAndHead,
    headCloseAndBodyOpen,
    bodyOpenTailAndContentBeforeApp,
    contentAfterAppAndHtmlClose,
  ] = fs.readFileSync('index.html', 'utf8').match(/^([\s\S]+?<html)([\s\S]+?)(<\/head>[\s\S]*?<body)([\s\S]+?)<div id="?app"?><\/div>([\s\S]+)$/);

  return {
    entire,
    htmlOpen,
    htmlOpenTailAndHead,
    headCloseAndBodyOpen,
    bodyOpenTailAndContentBeforeApp,
    contentAfterAppAndHtmlClose,
  };
}

const indexHtml = parseIndexHtml();
const app = express();

const basicAuth = auth.basic({
  realm: 'Jobportal',
}, (username, password, callback) => {
  callback(username === 'x' && password === 'x');
});

app.get('/ping', (request, response) => {
  response.status(200).end();
});

app.use(auth.connect(basicAuth));

// serve pure static assets
app.use('/public', express.static(path.resolve('./public')));
app.use('/dist', express.static(path.resolve('./dist')));

app.get('*', (request, response) => {
  const context = {
    url: request.url,
  };

  renderer.renderToString(context, (error, html) => {
    if (error) {
      if (error.code === '404') {
        response.status(404).end(indexHtml.entire);
      } else {
        response.status(500).end(indexHtml.entire);
        console.error(`Error during render: ${request.url}`); // eslint-disable-line
        console.error(error); // eslint-disable-line
      }
      return;
    }

    const {
      title,
      htmlAttrs,
      bodyAttrs,
      link,
      style,
      script,
      noscript,
      meta,
    } = context.meta.inject();

    response.write(
      `${indexHtml.htmlOpen} data-vue-meta-server-rendered ${htmlAttrs.text()} ${indexHtml.htmlOpenTailAndHead}
      ${meta.text()}
      ${title.text()}
      ${link.text()}
      ${style.text()}
      ${script.text()}
      <script>
        window.__INITIAL_STATE__ = ${JSON.stringify(context.initialState)}
      </script>
      ${noscript.text()}
      ${indexHtml.headCloseAndBodyOpen} ${bodyAttrs.text()} ${indexHtml.bodyOpenTailAndContentBeforeApp}
      ${html}
      <script src="/dist/client.js"></script>
      ${indexHtml.contentAfterAppAndHtmlClose}`
    );

    response.end();
  });
});

const port = 8181;

// start server
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`server started at port ${port}`); // eslint-disable-line
});
```

I get an error

```
server started at port 8181
events.js:163
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: bind EADDRINUSE null:8181
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1050:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1073:20)
    at listenOnMasterHandle (net.js:1336:16)
    at rr (internal/cluster/child.js:111:12)
    at Worker.send (internal/cluster/child.js:78:7)
    at process.onInternalMessage (internal/cluster/utils.js:42:8)
    at emitTwo (events.js:111:20)
    at process.emit (events.js:194:7)
    at process.nextTick (internal/child_process.js:766:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
events.js:163
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
```

Any ideas why ?

Comment: You should post your `startServer` code. Looking at the error, you might need to explicitly set the IP address or hostname of your server.

Comment: @Sebastian-LaurenţiuPlesciuc I have added the code. Thanks

Comment: You need to verify if the port is already taken on your system.

Comment: @KingReload Its not taken i have even changed it to 8080 still get the same error. This was working before and my old code was like this:
`var cluster = require('cluster');

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  // Count the machine's CPUs
  var cpuCount = require('os').cpus().length;

  // Create a worker for each CPU
  for (var i = 0; i < cpuCount; i += 1) {
    cluster.fork();
  }

  // Listen for dying workers
  cluster.on('exit', function () {
    cluster.fork();
  });
} else {
  require('./server');
}`

Comment: @Momo I have posted an answer to test if the port is taken or not

Comment: @Momo did you find the answer yet? I'm very curious :)

Comment: @KingReload Yes i did fix it :) please checkout the answer i posted :) Thanks again for your help

Comment: @KingReload Thanks. How can i do so? :)

Comment: @Momo below the up and down vote thing is a V, just click on it ;)

Comment: @Momo there you go ^^

Comment: @KingReload ;) Cool. Thanks have a nice day

Comment: @Momo have a nice day :)

Answer (score 2):

`EADDRINUSE` means that the port number which `listen()` tries to bind the server to is already in use.

You need to verify if the port is already taken on your system. To do that:

- On linux: `sudo netstat -nltp | grep (port)` in your case is port 8181.
- On OSX: `sudo lsof -i -P | grep (port)`

If you have a result, you need to `kill` the process (`kill <pid>`).

You should check if `pm2 list` returns 0 process. In addition, when you do a `pm2 stopAll`, the socket is not released. Don't forget to do a `pm2 kill` to be sure the daemon is killed.

```
$ pm2 kill
Daemon killed
```

Verifying for Windows:

```
C:\> netstat -a -b
```

- `a` Displays all connections and listening ports.
- `b` Displays the executable involved in creating each connection or listening port. In some cases well-known executables host multiple independent components, and in these cases the sequence of components involved in creating the connection or listening port is displayed. In this case the executable name is in [] at the bottom, on top is the component it called, and so forth until TCP/IP was reached. Note that this option can be time-consuming and will fail unless you have sufficient permissions.
- `n` Displays addresses and port numbers in numerical form.
- `o` Displays the owning process ID associated with each connection.

EXAMPLES to kill in windows command line:

If you know the name of a process to kill, for `example` notepad.exe, use the following command from a command prompt to end it:

```
taskkill /IM notepad.exe
```

To kill a single instance of a process, specify its process id (PID). For `example`, if the desired process has a PID of 827, use the following command to kill it:

```
taskkill /PID 827
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, i have already tried it out and the port  is free to be used i get no answer.

Comment: @Momo note `server started at port 8181` in your console, means it already connects, but after that you try to connect another time

Comment: correct ! and i guess it has to do with my if statement !

Comment: Hope it helped ;) if you encounter `EADDRINUSE` again, it means the server tries to connect twice to the same address/port

Comment: Thanks for your help. I still cant solve my problem :) with the code in cluster.js

Comment: `app.listen(port, () => {` and `return startServer;` do the same, try to put them on different ports, plus the `else {` in the `cluster.js` is meant for further processing. Here's a good example how to possibly resolve it: https://codeforgeek.com/2014/12/cluster-node-js-performance/

Comment: basically instead of `return startServer;` put inside it `require("./server.js");`. then in your console run `node cluster.js`.

Comment: `return startServer;` in cluster.js meant to only call/run server.js.

Comment: @Momo have you looked at the documentation I send as well? #the wesbite

Comment: Yes i did. with this code it works 
`var cluster = require('cluster');
if (cluster.isMaster) {
  // Count the machine's CPUs
  var cpuCount = require('os').cpus().length;

  // Create a worker for each CPU
  for (var i = 0; i < cpuCount; i += 1) {
    cluster.fork();
  }

  // Listen for dying workers
  cluster.on('exit', function () {
    cluster.fork();
  });
} else {
  require('./server.js');
}`
But i need to use the new way of writing which all require should be in top level and instead of var i use const. This where my problem came from. trying to convert this code

Comment: So you came to the solution? :)

Comment: No i didnt with this code it works `var cluster = require('cluster'); if (cluster.isMaster) { // Count the machine's CPUs var cpuCount = require('os').cpus().length; // Create a worker for each CPU for (var i = 0; i < cpuCount; i += 1) { cluster.fork(); } // Listen for dying workers cluster.on('exit', function () { cluster.fork(); }); } else { require('./server.js'); }` But i need to use the new way of writing which all require should be in top level and instead of var i use const. This where my problem came from. trying to convert this code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143372/discussion-between-king-reload-and-momo).